# C++ conditions inside return statement

Tags: c++

Is there a way to do this

```
bool retA = true, retB=false retC=true,retD=false;

return ( (if RetA -> A) + (if RetB -> B) + (if RetC -> C) + (if RetD -> A) )
```

Basically if {A,B,C,D] = {1,2,3,4}, return value is 1+0+3+0 = 4. You can do this with 16 different if/else statements, but the code is not pretty.

Comment: You could try ternary operator (I forget its real name) eg `(RetA ? A : 0) + ..`

Comment: Compound if statement

Comment: You can also do this with 4 if statements, not 16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for the conditional operator, which looks like this:
 `testExpression ? trueExpression : falseExpression`.

So:

```
return (retA ? A : 0) + (retB ? B : 0) + (retC ? C : 0) + (retD ? D : 0);
```

All of the languages syntactically derived from B have the conditional operator (C, C++, Java, JavaScript, and several others).

---

Side note: You were using `A` after the `RetD` condition, but I figure you meant `D`. Also, no need for the outer pair of `()`, so I left them off.

---

You'll sometimes hear the conditional operator called "the ternary operator," which is fine but isn't quite correct: It's ***a*** ternary operator (that is, an operator that accepts three operands) just like `*` is ***a*** binary operator (an operator that accepts two operands). As far as I know, the conditional is C++'s only ternary operator, but in theory someday there could be more...